# Apply class only to the elements with the class and not all children

Tags: css

I need to apply style only to the elements that has the class "red". How do I avoid applying the class to all children town the stream?

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li class="red">item
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li class="red">item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By overriding the color of the children with some other `CSS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply CSS to all immediate children of `.red` using `> *`. Reset `color` to `initial` to ignore any previous styling (from the element's parents).

```css
.red {
  color: red
}

.red > * {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li class="red">item
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li class="red">item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of your HTML, consider inserting an element containing only the text you want styled. For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li><em class="red">item</em>
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li><em  class="red">item</em></li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your original document, the nested `ul` is part of the `li` with a class of red. This means that the `red` styling will take effect as well. This may allow for less complex CSS and greater semantics in the HTML document.